# Regex to verify url don't work as i expect

Tags: regex

I have found the following pattern which verify an url [here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) :

```
/\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i;
```

the explanation of this regex from author is :

```
(?xi)
\b
(                       # Capture 1: entire matched URL
  (?:
    https?://               # http or https protocol
    |                       #   or
    www\d{0,3}[.]           # "www.", "www1.", "www2." … "www999."
    |                           #   or
    [a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/  # looks like domain name followed by a slash
  )
  (?:                       # One or more:
    [^\s()<>]+                  # Run of non-space, non-()<>
    |                           #   or
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
  )+
  (?:                       # End with:
    \(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)  # balanced parens, up to 2 levels
    |                               #   or
    [^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]        # not a space or one of these punct chars
  )
)
```

the problem is that if i type `www.ab` this regex work and say that is a valid url, what i want is obligatory that this url should have 2 last parts : "**foobar**" + **.** + **(minimum 2 characters)** , so how i can modify this Regex to match what i need ?

Comment: was it not better to try simple regex for such requirement rather than starting with such a complex one?

Comment: URLs don't always have three parts, `www` is often omitted.

Comment: @jkshah are simple regex really catch all (majority) urls ?

Comment: Also, www.org is for example a valid URL.

Comment: @medBo agree. but many urls don't have constraints like `url should have 3 parts : [www] + . + "foobar" + . + (minimum 2 characters)`. This constraint should make regex easier, AFAIK.

Comment: @GergoErdosi yes i know that www is often omitted, i tried to render it optional by wrapping www part in the regex like (www\d{0,3}[.])? and it works only if i put just url like google.com, if i add a text before like "foobar google.com" it catch foobar rather than google.com

Comment: @medBo Ok, but if it is optional, `"foobar" + . + (minimum 2 characters)` would still match `www.ab`. So don't exactly understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @GergoErdosi i remove it from my question, www part is not verry important for me, and also i find that you are right that www.org is a valid url :)

Comment: @GergoErdosi have you any suggestion to render www optional and accept also a text before like foobartext google.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You originally indicated you wanted a regular expression to match a three part URL: www, a domain name, and a minimum 2 character TLD.  That would be:

```
(https?://)?[^.]+\.[^.]+\....*
```

I am using dots here to handle the situation of numbers and non-Latin characters in the domain and the TLD.

If you want to support one or more sub-domains, we can make that regex more generic.  Consider:

```
(https?://)?([^.]+\.)+...*
```

This still matches www.ab, though -- that's a "valid" URL per the specification of "domain" + "." + "tld" (minimum of two characters).  It also matches www.45, but you didn't stipulate what made a TLD valid.

So ultimately consider following some [sage advice](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/280-how-to-validate-urls-with-regular-expressions/):

> Which ... regular expressions should you use? That really depends
>   on what you’re trying to do. In many situations, the answer may be to
>   not use any regular expression at all. Simply try to resolve the URL.
>   If it returns valid content, accept it. If you get a 404 or other
>   error, reject it. Ultimately, that’s the only real test to see whether
>   a URL is valid

Comment: thank you @bishop for explanation i'm agree with you, so you can just add some explanation for each part in your regex

Answer (score 0):

```
/\bwww\.\w+\.\w{2,}/
```

This will match `www.any_alfa_numeric_combo.two_or_more_alfa_nemeric`